# Android Studio issue cmake

Tags: android

I have issue like this, when I want to rebuild my project.

Cause: executing external native build for cmake /home/hovsep/Documents/GITLAB/moon/Android/branches/Dev-Main/app/CMakeLists.txt

how can I fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The error text you see is "top level". There may be anything behind it.

Need to look into log files like:

```
./app/.cxx/cmake/commonDebug/x86/android_gradle_generate_cmake_ninja_json_x86.stderr.txt
```

Do not know how to find all logs. I searched it in linux with:

```
find -mmin -1
```

That helped me to find the real issue in correspondent log files.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to one of two problems.

1. You also need to install ncurses5 as Android Studio doesn't support later versions, you may not have it or you may have a later version installed on your computer.

To **reinstall** ncurses5 open terminal in Ubuntu and type:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libncurses5-dev
```

To **install** ncurses5 open terminal in Ubuntu and type :

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

OR

2. The problem is the wrong location of CMakelist.txt file.

Try to move CMakelist.txt file from your app root directory to app/src/main/cpp/CMakelist.txt directory and then update the location from gradle file also like this:

```
externalNativeBuild {
cmake {
    path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
      }
}
```

Otherwise IDK sorry.

Comment: how to install ncurses5 on ubuntu16.04

Comment: Edited post now you should be able to install. If not then idk just look it up I'm not very familiar with this software. @user1899045